# Invertibility and Rank of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can anyone give me a proof for,

B is an invertible $n$x$n$ matrix, then the rank of $AB$ is the same as the rank of $A$ for every $m$x$n$ matrix $A$.

Also, is the converse true for the statement above?

Comment: Let's see the matrices as linear maps between vectorspaces. $rg(AB)=dim(im(AB))=dim(im(A|_{im(B)})=dim(im(A))=rg(A)$ because $B$ is surjective and so $im(B)$ is the whole vestorspace.

Comment: The converse is also true. Let $B$ be a $nxn$ matrix with that property. Then $rg(B)=rg(IB)=rg(I)=n$ where $I$ is the $nxn$ unit matrix. So $B$ is a quadratic matrix with full rank, hence invertible.

Comment: Archipielago, I suggest you post your answers as answers and not as comments.

Comment: @archipelago Is there another way to prove this without looking at matrices as linear maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my proof for a stronger version of your statement, Mark. This is a proof that if $B$ is invertible, $rank(A)=rank(BA)=rank(AB)$.

The rank is the $n$ - $\dim$(nullspace) right? So make sure that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same sized nullspace as $A$.

But $Ax=0$ if and only if $BAx=0$. That is true because $B$ is invertible. So $rank(BA)=rank(A)$ because they have the same row nullspace.

Since the dimension of the row and column nullspaces are the same, this also works to show that $xA=0$ if an only if $xAB=0$, giving $rank(AB)=rank(A)$, since they have the same column nullspace.

Comment: But I'm talking about A as $m$x$n$ matrix. So BA doesn't exist since we cannot get BxA. Is the statement going to work even though BA doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For the first part, prove that

$$\dim(Col(AB))= \dim (Col(A)) \,.$$

This follows easily from $z \in Col(A) \Leftrightarrow Ax=z$ is consistent, while 
$ w \in Col(AB) \Leftrightarrow ABx=w$ is consistent.

For the second part: 
**Hint** If $B$ is not invertible, show that you can find a row vector $A \neq 0$ so that $AB=0$. What is $rank(AB)$ and what can you say about $rank(A)$?

Comment: I don't know any of those terminologies. Is there any other way to prove this?